# How can I customize TabBar's indicator and Label in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

i want this expected : [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZBjp.jpg) tapbar in flutter but what is get is: [what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yovwL.jpg). I did not know how to get single label's name but all indicator i.e selected and unselected, based on indicator i want to scroll. below is my code:

```
                    DefaultTabController(
                    length: stages.length,
                    initialIndex: 0,
                    child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          height: 60.0,
                          width: width,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: TabBar(
                            isScrollable: true,
                            labelColor: Colors.teal,
                            indicatorColor: Colors.teal,
                            indicatorWeight: 2.0,
                            labelPadding:  EdgeInsets.only(right: 250.0, left: 40.0),
                            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                            tabs: List<Widget>.generate(stages.length,
                                    (int index) {
                                  String neStageName = stages[index];
                                  // print(dealList[0]);
                                  return new Tab(
                                      child: Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            CircleAvatar(
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                                                child: Text( neStageName[0].toUpperCase())),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: Text(neStageName,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 22.0)),
                                            )
                                          ]));
                                }),
                          )),
                      Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          child: TabBarView(
                            children: List<Widget>.generate(stages.length,
                                    (int index) {
                                  stageName = stages[index];
                                  return FutureBuilder(
                                      future: _dealHelper.getDealPerStages(pipeId, stageName),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        return snapshot.data != null
                                            ? getLeadList(snapshot.data) : getLeadInListView();
                                      });
                                }),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: For that(your image), you create your own using PageView.

Comment: thanks for your comment but my problem was on Tab's indicator and if i use PageView my problem will not solve.

Comment: How can you say that? Looking at your image im saying, you can make tab indicators small but I dont think you can achieve exact same like your expected screenshot.

Comment: i agreed with your answer but i did not get the result by using PageView also.

Comment: Yes, you have to do some stuff to transition and selections